# Initialize Node aws with profile

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to read from a *S3 Bucket*, currently I have the code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'myAccesID', secretAccessKey: 'superRandomSecretKey', region: 'us-west-2'});
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var params = {
 Bucket: 'my-bucket',
 Delimiter: '/'
}

s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
 if(err)throw err;
 console.log(data);
});
```

But I get `Access Denied`, I know that my *named profile* works because I can list my files with the `aws cli` command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket --recursive --profile  my-named-profile
```

So, how can I initialize my `aws` instance with a ***named profile***?

Comment: If its instance, why not use IAM role for the instance, instead of hard codding the credentials?

Comment: That's my question

Answer (score -1):

The recommended way to access S3 from an instance is through [IAM roles for Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html).

The basic role could just contain AWS Managed policy `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess`:

[image]

Having the role attached to your instance, you don't need to do anything special for `aws-sdk` to use it. The **SDK will automatically recognize it**. Therefore, you could be:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var params = {
 Bucket: 'my-bucket',
 Delimiter: '/'
}

s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
 if(err)throw err;
 console.log(data);
});
```